# What do you do with the toilet brush after you clean the toilet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I mean, it’s wet and I don’t want to put it back in it’s holder until it’s dry to prevent mold/bacterial growth. And also it’s dirty. Am I supposed to rinse it in the sink?

Comment: rinse it when flushing after cleaning.

Comment: use bleach on the toilet, then the brush is sterile going into the holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would of course NOT rinse it in the sink.

You can put it back in the holder loosely so it will dry. Some holders have a trap door. On those prop the brush so the door stays open.

Answer (score 2):

You rinse it in the bowl once the bowl is clean. Flush once or twice as necessary to rinse all the cleaner out.

We usually put the handle flat across the rim of the bowl (with the brush over the bowl) then put the seat down to hold it there while we let it drip dry for an hour or two (or until someone needs to go). Don't put the lid down - it'll smash the top of the brush and get the lid wet.

You can get a fancy little holder for it that sits in the corner of the bathroom, or you can keep a metal or plastic bowl under the vanity that you can store the brush in. Either of those should accept the brush still lightly damp and contain the drips (of what should be just clean water at this point), preventing them from spreading and causing damage.